# Horizontally scrollable div not completely visible

Tags: css

I have the following code for tabs. But the problem is that because of the `left: 50px;` on `.sc-tabs` the last tab isn't completely visible. Setting `width: calc(100% + 50px);` of `.sc-tabs` only makes it worse. So my question is how can I make the `.sc-tabs` long enough to show all `.sc-tab-icon-text`?

```css
.sc-tabs {
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 .28571rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144264), 0 .21429rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.236);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 .28571rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144264), 0 .21429rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.236);
    box-shadow: 0 .28571rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144264), 0 .21429rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.236);
    background: #3F51B5;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 3.42857rem;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap
}
.sc-tabs:hover {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text {
    border-bottom: .14286rem solid #3F51B5;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    max-width: 18.85714rem;
    min-width: 5.14286rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-transition: border 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: border 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text:hover {
    border-bottom: .14286rem solid #fff;
    color: #fff
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text .material-icons {
    width: 1.71429rem;
    height: 1.71429rem;
    font-size: 1.71429rem
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text {
    height: 5.14286rem;
    padding: .71429rem .85714rem 1.14286rem .85714rem
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text span {
    display: block;
    margin: .71429rem 0 0 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sc-tabs">
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>5</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>6</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>7</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>8</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>9</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>10</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use flexbox?

Comment: @hunzaboy Yes it's possible

Comment: i think what you need is to show all the icons and text in single line right?

Comment: _“Setting width: calc(100% + 50px); of .sc-tabs only makes it worse”_ – of course it does, because that _increases_ the element width even more, instead of decreasing it. You failed to describe what result you actually want to achieve here - but if you just want the element to be 50px from both sides, then remove the width and add `right: 50px;`

Comment: @CBroe "You failed to describe what result you actually want to achieve here" I say it isn't completely visible meaning I want it to be. If I wanted it to be 50px from both sides I would have set it

Comment: @SuperDJ there are many ways to solve your problem, but we need to know what exactly you want?

Comment: @hunzaboy I want it to be scrollable and it should be 50px from the left. All I want is that all `.sc-tab-icon-text` are visible when scrolling.

Comment: Well then set right to 0, if you want it there …

Comment: @SuperDJ : did you checked my fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is the solution:

```
.sc-tabs {
   width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.sc-tabs {
  width: 96%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 2%;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

If you want to set space from left. then give it in % and make so that overall it becomes 100%; **left+right+width**

```css
.sc-tabs {
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 .28571rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144264), 0 .21429rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.236);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 .28571rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144264), 0 .21429rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.236);
    box-shadow: 0 .28571rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144264), 0 .21429rem .57143rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.236);
    background: #3F51B5;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 3.42857rem;
    width: 96%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 2%;
    white-space: nowrap
}
.sc-tabs:hover {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text {
    border-bottom: .14286rem solid #3F51B5;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    max-width: 18.85714rem;
    min-width: 5.14286rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-transition: border 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: border 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text:hover {
    border-bottom: .14286rem solid #fff;
    color: #fff
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text .material-icons {
    width: 1.71429rem;
    height: 1.71429rem;
    font-size: 1.71429rem
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text {
    height: 5.14286rem;
    padding: .71429rem .85714rem 1.14286rem .85714rem
}
.sc-tabs .sc-tab-icon-text span {
    display: block;
    margin: .71429rem 0 0 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sc-tabs">
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>5</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>6</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>7</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>8</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>9</span></div>
  <div class="sc-tab-icon-text"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>10</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough solution. I have used display: table, instead of your block and other properties. This will help you to achieve whatever you want in proper way.

https://jsfiddle.net/ko6xtw1g/

```
.sc-tabs{display: table;} .sc-tab-icon-text{display: table-cell;}
```

i also have removed the left: 50%;

Comment: Not yet what I'm looking for

Comment: is just a rough idea of how you can do. What's the issue?

Comment: so you only need the left spacing. check this one https://jsfiddle.net/ko6xtw1g/2/

Comment: You made a mistake in the fiddle. After `white-space: nowrap` you forgot `;` which doesn't make it `display: table;`. When it is displayed as table it breaks though.